# Update textbox with text from browsed file. python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, textbox

I am currently using Python 2.7 and Tkinter. I have a button that browses my directory and takes the file's directory location and saves it to `filename`. I would like this to change the value of `inputBox` to the value of `filename` automatically when the file is chosen.

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

root = Tk()

root.title("Doc Word Frequency")
root.geometry("600x300")

def close_window (): 
    root.destroy()

def browse_directory():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    print(filename)

    #Change value of inputBox

inputBox = Entry(root, width = 50)
inputBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 20)
inputBox.insert(END, '"Upload Document File"')
inputBox.config(state = DISABLED)

Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Browse', command = browse_directory).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W, padx = 4)
Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Upload').grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 4)
Button(root, width = 9, text = 'Quit', command = close_window).grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W, padx = 4)

mainloop( )
```

PS. I am quite new to Python and any constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert text into an entry widget with the [insert](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method) method.

```
def browse_directory():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    print(filename)

    inputBox.configure(state=NORMAL)
    inputBox.delete(0, "end")
    inputBox.insert(0, filename)
    inputBox.configure(state=DISABLED)
```