# Updating file path upon getting directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and trying to create a GUI that requires and input and output directory. My goal is to have a textbox new to a browse button and when the directory is selected the textbox will display the directory path. However, I am not sure how to change the text displayed when the button is clicked within the function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        T_out= tk.Text(root, height=1, width=50)
        T_out.pack(side=TOP)
        self.hi_there= Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.getoutputdir)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
        T_in = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=50)
        T_in.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.input_1= Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.getinputdir)
        self.input_1.pack(side=LEFT)

    def getoutputdir(self):
        global outputdir
        outputdir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select the output directory')
        T_out.text(tk.END,outputdir)
    def getinputdir(self):
        global inputdir
        inputdir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select the input directory')
        T_in.text(tk.END,inputdir)
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI for CZI')
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update textbox with text from browsed file. python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047225/update-textbox-with-text-from-browsed-file-python) ... also [How do I update this Text Box's text in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502418/how-do-i-update-this-text-boxs-text-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues preventing this from working. The first is in the `getinputdir` and `getoutputdir` functions. You need to make sure that the references to the `T_in` and `T_out` are available. You can do this by storing them in the App object.

The second main issue is `.text` is not a valid method. You can use `.delete` to clear it then `.insert` to insert the new directory.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.T_out= tk.Text(root, height=1, width=50)
        self.T_out.pack(side=TOP)
        self.hi_there= Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.getoutputdir)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.T_in = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=50)
        self.T_in.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.input_1= Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.getinputdir)
        self.input_1.pack(side=LEFT)

    def getoutputdir(self):
        global outputdir
        outputdir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select the output directory')
        self.T_out.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.T_out.insert(tk.END, outputdir)
    def getinputdir(self):
        global inputdir
        inputdir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select the input directory')
        self.T_in.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.T_in.insert(tk.END, inputdir)
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI for CZI')
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ! really appreciate it